# What is absolutely the easiest way to create and publish a Rails 3.0 application from Windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment

In an attempt to reach programming enlightenment, I'm trying to build my latest website within the Rails ecosystem. I'm finding this very hard going as a .Net developer and need a push in the right direction as I'm on the verge of giving up and going back to what I know.

I've got something approaching a prototype going in Rails, and have been trying to figure out how to get to the point where I have a sensible deployment set-up to publish a beta of this thing. I don't see any point in developing any further until I know I'll be able to publish in a sensible fashion.

So far, I have signed up for hosting at HostingRails, created an SVN repository at Google Code and installed Capistrano. The problem I'm now facing is that I have no idea how to alter my Capfile and Deploy.rb to get these talking to each other, and that's before I've even thought about database deployment. The problem is that the tutorials on the hosting provider aren't great and the documentation for Capistrano goes straight over my head. I'm at a point where Capistrano presents me with a password prompt, and no password relating to anything I know of seems to work. Capistrano doesn't give me a hint of what it's trying to do, and I have no idea how to verify any of the lines in my config file to find out what's wrong.

Can anyone suggest a complete toolchain that will allow me to publish an application with as little configuration as possible? Am I going in vaguely the right direction and will this also give me sensible DB deployment options? Can anyone suggest a simple step-by-step guide which doesn't require an understanding of 37 separate gems before deployment is possible?

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest git and [heroku](http://heroku.com/) for rails projects rather than svn and HostingRails. [msysgit](https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) works well on Windows, and I just started using heroku and it's as easy as installing the heroku gem and doing "git push heroku master".

Comment: +1 Another good reason for git/heroku is that there's a really good free tutorial online (or you can buy the book/pdf/screencasts) at http://railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book .